# Change table structure for mobile using single markup

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a simple bootstrap table(as in the code below). I want that in my mobile view each row entry should be displayed separately inside a box or a card. For example,
First card -

```
First: Mark
Last : Otto
Handle: @mdo
```

Second card-

```
First:Jacob
Last:Thornton
Handle:@fat
```

and so on. Is it possible to manipulate this design without having to write separate HTML for mobile view? Either through css or javascript? ( I am using bootstrap 4)

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply restyle each element the way you like them to look. However you can't insert information unless it's static, or present as an attribute on an element, that's why I've inserted the `col` attribute on each `td` element. For example:

```js
document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = () => {
  const table = document.getElementById('table');
  table.classList.toggle('cards');
}
```

```css
.cards thead {
  display: none;
}

.cards tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cards tr > th {
  display: none;
}

.cards tr > td::before {
  content: attr(col) ': ';
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">Toggle Style</button>
<table class="table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td col="First">Mark</td>
      <td col="Last">Otto</td>
      <td col="Handle">@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td col="First">Jacob</td>
      <td col="Last">Thornton</td>
      <td col="Handle">@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td col="First">Larry</td>
      <td col="Last">the Bird</td>
      <td col="Handle">@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Q**: How can I increase the space between the heading and data in the flex view?
**A**: By adjusting the padding on the right hand side of the `::before` element.

```js
document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = () => {
  const table = document.getElementById('table');
  table.classList.toggle('cards');
}
```

```css
.cards thead {
  display: none;
}

.cards tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cards tr > th {
  display: none;
}

.cards tr > td::before {
  content: attr(col) ': ';
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">Toggle Style</button>
<table class="table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td col="First">Mark</td>
      <td col="Last">Otto</td>
      <td col="Handle">@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td col="First">Jacob</td>
      <td col="Last">Thornton</td>
      <td col="Handle">@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td col="First">Larry</td>
      <td col="Last">the Bird</td>
      <td col="Handle">@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh great! Worked like a treat! I didn't know we could change the structure like this. Thanks !! :)

Comment: @HarshVardhanBandta no problem! You can do quite a lot with modern CSS that most ppl would resort to javascript for.

Comment: How can I increase the space between the heading and data in the flex view?By adding content: attr(col) ': '; it adds one space. If I want it to be more, how can I do that? I tried &nbsp but it gives error and adding padding and margin is also not helping.

Comment: @HarshVardhanBandta I've answered your question in the original post.